# Output with value greater than 0

Tags: batch-file, count, find, output

I want to output a count with the following script:

```
@find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\Sc0320svr0001\e$\Users\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\*.dbg" >>output.txt
```

However, I only want to export values greater than 0.

This currently outputs:

```
---------- \\SC0320SVR0001\E$\USERS\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\PED_20140812_092355.DBG: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try testing the last char of the output :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\Sc0320svr0001\e$\Users\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\*.dbg"') do (
  set "$line=%%a"
  set "$lastchar=!$line:~-1!"
  if !$lastchar! gtr 0 echo %%a >>output.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@find /c /i "Error   : -2" "\\Sc0320svr0001\e$\Users\SC0320POS0003\E2ELOGS\*.dbg" |findstr /i /v /c:": 0">>output.txt
```

`Findstr` switches have different meanings to `find`.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file


% or %% (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```